# Create Binding with multiple inputs

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I want to make a binding, when `buttonA` is pressed (changing value from false to true)`lightIsTurnedOn` turns `true` (indepedend of value of buttonB), when another `buttonB` is pressed (changing value from false to true) `lightIsTurnedOn` turns `false` (independend of value of buttonA). 
Is it possible to handle that with a Binding?

```
private final BooleanBinding lightIsTurnedOn;
private final BooleanProperty buttonA= new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
private final BooleanProperty buttonB = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
```

Comment: And then on the next press? what should turn it from true to false? Don't you need two toggles? (If one of them are "On" the light is on, if both of them are "Off", the light is off)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a perfect task for [`ToggleButton`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html):

```
ToggleButton buttonA = new ToggleButton("A");
ToggleButton buttonB = new ToggleButton("B");

Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(buttonA.selectedProperty().or(buttonB.selectedProperty()).asString());
```

The text of the `Label` will change to `"true"` whenever at least one of the `ToggleButton`s are "switched on" and will change to `"false"` if both of them are "switched off".

Answer (score 0):

No this is impossible to do with a binding. The value of a binding is computed by a `computeValue` method (at least without storing additional information somewhere). This method does not get any parameters. It simply does not have any information about which dependency was invalidated last.

Therefore it's impossible to distinguish the following sequences of modifications

```
buttonA pressed
buttonB pressed
```

and

```
buttonB pressed
buttonA pressed
```

However the results are `lightIsTurnedOn` being `false`/`true`.

---

However of course something like this is possible, even though simply adding listeners to the properties that set the value would be preferable.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ToggleButton buttonA = new ToggleButton("A");
    ToggleButton buttonB = new ToggleButton("B");
    Circle light = new Circle(30, Color.YELLOW);
    light.visibleProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {


        boolean lastA = false;
        boolean lastB = false;

        {
            bind(buttonA.selectedProperty(), buttonB.selectedProperty());
        }

        boolean value = false;

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            boolean a = buttonA.isSelected();
            boolean b = buttonB.isSelected();
            if (lastA != a && a) {
                value = true;
            }

            if (lastB != b && b) {
                value = false;
            }
            lastA = a;
            lastB = b;
            return value;
        }
    });

    HBox root = new HBox(buttonA, buttonB, light);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```